# How does app.get() work on the server file?

Tags: node.js, express, get

I am trying to understand how app.get() works in calling functions when trying to switch between web pages.

I've created a user-login page that assigns a token to the user and checks it in a function.

I use `app.post('/login', login);` to call the login function which sends the user object to the server. After creating the token I'm hoping to then render the next page in a function after checking the token. (See code below)

However, I don't really understand how `app.get('/', checkToken, getProfilePage)` is then called. As I don't think it ever gets called.

I've looked at some websites that explain about HTTP requests but I'm struggling to find out, how it all links together inside app.js.

`App.js`:

```
app.post('/login', login);
app.get('/', authorize.checkToken, getProfilePage);

function login(req, res, next) {
 userService.login(req.body, (err, user) => {
    if (err) {
        res.redirect('error.ejs');
        console.log(error.message);
    }
    console.log(user);
    if (!user) {
      res.status(400).json({ success: false, message: 'Username or 
 password is incorrect' });
    }
    else {
      res.json(user);
    }
    })
}
```

The next login function assigns the token and is used above as middleware:

```
function login({ username, password }, callback) {
grabUsers((err, users) => {
    let user = users.find(u => u.username === username && u.password 
=== password);
    if (user) {
        const token = jwt.sign({ username: username }, config.secret, 
            { expiresIn: '24h'
        }
        );
        const { password, ...userWithoutPassword } = user;
        user = {
            ...userWithoutPassword,
            success: true,
            message: 'Authentication successful!',
            token: token
        }
    };  
    callback(null,user);
    })
```

}

Inside `authorize.js`:

```
let jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const config = require('./config.js');

let checkToken = (req, res, next) => {
    console.log("check token running...");
  let token = req.headers['x-access-token'] || 
 req.headers['authorization']; // Express headers are auto 
 converted to lowercase
  if (token.startsWith('Bearer ')) {
    // Remove Bearer from string
    token = token.slice(7, token.length);
  }

 if (token) {
   jwt.verify(token, config.secret, (err, decoded) => {
   if (err) {
    return res.json({
      success: false,
      message: 'Token is not valid'
    });
  } else {
    req.decoded = decoded;
    next();
  }
   });
  } else {
 return res.json({
  success: false,
  message: 'Auth token is not supplied'
 });
  }
};

module.exports = {
 checkToken: checkToken }
```

`getProfilePage` function:

```
module.exports = {
    getProfilePage: (req, res) => {
        res.render('profile.ejs');
    }
}
```

So my login form posts to `/login` and then once it has been verified I would like to check the token and then call `getProfilePage`. But how do I call the app.get() after the login data has been posted and authenticated?

Comment: When do you generate the token? Do you send it back to the client inside `user` object?

Comment: Apologies I have added this to my code

Comment: Yeah, thanks, as I thought. Have my answer helped you?

Comment: I'm just working through it now. But it seems like it's helped me. I will tick if correct at some point.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand where the authorization header is set when assigning my token? I'm using different tutorials to assign jwt tokens and none of them explain that the authorisation header is being set. So where in my code do i set the authorisation header? In my checktoken middleware I get undefined when checking the req.header?

Comment: Have you tried the solution I posted? You'd better set a cookie and not authorization header. If you want to proceed with `authorization` header you'd have to set it for EVERY request you make which isn't possible for example when you want to just fetch a profile page by pasting URL in browser's address bar. That's why I pointed out that `authorization` header is a valid solution for API authorization, but not for keeping user's session.

Comment: Cookies are always sent with the request, that's the difference with other custom headers

Comment: Yh I was trying to compare the two, so if I understand correctly authorization simply lets third-party applications use my API, whereas for creating authentication on a web app I would use your suggestion so they have access to all pages once logged in?

So if I were to use cookies (which this link https://logrocket.com/blog/jwt-authentication-best-practices/ says not to use with JWT) I am unsure on how to add a userId into my jwt token. I may have to go back to the drawing board on this.

Comment: I suggest you to read those 3 articles about using JWT for sessions (at the bottom of the article you mentioned). I can't say that using JWT as a session cookie is a bad idea, you just need to take into account all the disadvantages it has over using sessions stored in DBs. DB sessions are generally more flexible and powerful than JWT, but it doesn't mean you can't/shouldn't use JWT. One can mess things up even using DB sessions easily if doesn't know well how they work. So, while you use HTTPOnly, secure cookies you'll be fine with JWT in terms of security.

Comment: You add `userId` into your JWT the same way you added `username` to JWT in your code snippet above

Comment: And check out [`express-session`](https://github.com/expressjs/session) if you consider switching to DB sessions instead of JWT

Answer (score 0):

You don't call a route from your app, what you need to do is redirect to it : res.redirect('/');

Comment: Why shouldn't I call a route from my app? How does res.redirect('/') fit into ensuring the token has been authorized?

Comment: Cause calling a route is a client job not the server so redirect tell the client to call that route.

Comment: By telling the client to open a route by redirect or javascript or whaterver the route middleware are called thus a verification is made. Again if your problem is after veriying the token you want to load the route you have to know "next" is the function to call with no arguments. The function checktoken is a Middleware.

Comment: I think I'm getting confused with the term client and server... can you give me an example of a client calling route inside an app? In my head, a client is simply the computer accessing the app on a browser. Would the client be a file in my app maybe?

Comment: You are doing server side programing so it doesn't make sense to even call a route as you can call the function directly. But what you want is a client ( ex : browser) to call the route ( here "/" ) so you have a couple of choice either by javascript or by redirect ( after client called  "/login" server tell browser to open "/" instead of just showing the result of "/login"

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a problem with how you try to authenticate a user. Seems to me you send a token in `authorization` header which is a common practice when you accessing API. Not sure how/when you generate the token and set this header though...

Anyway, this approach is good for authorization but not so good for authentication.

After successful `/login` request you should set the authentication cookie (user session). To simplify, you can just generate a JWT with `userId` encoded into it and use it as the value for this cookie (let's call it `user-session`).

Now after that each time user makes a request the cookie will be sent with it and you can decode the `userId` from this JWT. (Same thing, but now you'll take token from `req.cookies['user-session']` instead of `req.headers['authorization']`).

> But how do I call the app.get() after the login data has been posted and authenticated?

You can either navigate to this page from the client right after you receive successful `/login` response if you're using AJAX (i.e. `window.location.replace('/')`) or you can do `res.redirect('/')` instead of `res.json(user)` on successful login if you submit the HTML form without AJAX.

Redirect forces a browser to immediately make another request to the URL you specify and by that time you'll have `user-session` cookie set, i.e. you'll be able to retrieve `userId` and return correct profile page.